# Firebase function, get hashmap data from onCall

Tags: android, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a problem how i receive and use hashmaps in firebase function. I see the data being sent properly. But using it is a problem.

**How i send the data from the Android platform**

```
fun onStartChatClicked() {
    val functions = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance()
    val map = HashMap<String, String>()

    usersToChatWith.forEach {
        map.put(it.userId!!, it.username!!)
    }

    functions.getHttpsCallable("startChatWithUsers")
        .call(map)
        .continueWith {task ->
               if (task.isSuccessful) {

               } else {

               }
        }
}
```

I have also tried it with `hashMapOf()` function. Just in case :P

When i just print the receive data in the firebase function. I do get it like some typical Json string

```
{ '3SYIpex6u1Mx31j1UUngKAy95hq2': 'user1', JgoKrekU6nNusxeMBr6JAjkCReX2: 'user2' }
```

**Simplified firebase function code**

```
export const startChatWithUsers = functions.https.onCall(async (data , context) => {

        /** A little code */

        for (let [userId, username] of data) {
            /** some code */
        }

       /** Some more code */

    })
```

The problem lies in the function not being able to loop through the data given. Because if i understood it correctly. It does not think the data given is a map.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code in your question, it looks like you are trying to iterate on an object by getting the key-value pair of each entry in the object.

However, you’ve left out the `entries()` call that’s needed to turn the object into a collection of key-value pairs.

Try this for your for loop:

```
for (let [userId, username] of data.entries()) {
  /** some code */
}
```